# Почему YouTube видео несколько дней работает на своём сайте, а потом перестаёт?

Tags: iframe, youtube

Почему видео несколько дней работает, а потом перестаёт? Какие можно вставлять, а какие нет? Я сначала вставил iframe просто найденный в интернете, всё работало и перестало, потом взял код iframe-а с вк, а видео оставил то же, но снова не работает.

Comment: Что значит "перестает работать"? Опишите подробнее плиз.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Под видео есть Поделиться -> Встроить.

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/nuQ_z976w58" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Попробуйте, для начала, так. 
Еще может быть проблема с браузерами - попробуйте сменить браузер. Google начинает кешировать страницы для не-https сайтов. Ситуация такая, что если  ресурс закеширован, то видео может отсутствовать. Опция не работает в режиме "Инкогнито".